# Re-render View after updating @Bindable object from background task

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-data

I have a @Bindable Object in my view that a user should be able to update normally (adjusting the text in the TextField) or by triggering a background update task:

```swift
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct CarView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext: ModelContext
    @Bindable var car: Car

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("Car Name", text: $car.name)
            Text("logs: \(car.logs.count)")
            Text("kms: \(car.logs.map(\.km).reduce(0, +))")
            Button {
                // How to get this to re-render the view after the update to the Bindable Car?
                Task {
                    let logUpdater = LogUpdater(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
                    try await logUpdater.update(car.persistentModelID)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Update")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

@Model
class Car {
    var name: String
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Log.car) var logs: [Log]

    init(name: String, logs: [Log] = []) {
        self.name = name
        self.logs = logs
    }
}

@Model class Log {
    var km: Int
    var car: Car?

    init(km: Int, car: Car? = nil) {
        self.km = km
        self.car = car
    }
}

@ModelActor
actor LogUpdater {
    // mimics background network call update
    func update(_ identifier: PersistentIdentifier) async throws {
        guard let car = modelContext.model(for: identifier) as? Car else { return  }
        var logs = [Log]()
        for _ in 0...50 {
            let log = Log(km: .random(in: 100...200))
            logs.append(log)
        }
        car.logs.append(contentsOf: logs)
        try modelContext.save()
    }
}

#Preview {
    let config = ModelConfiguration(isStoredInMemoryOnly: true)
    let container = try! ModelContainer(for: Car.self, configurations: config)
    let car = Car(name: "VW")
    return CarView(car: car)
        .modelContainer(container)
}
```

While the normal view update with TextField is fine... how can I ensure that the @Bindable object is updated, or rather, triggers an update to the view after new logs are added to the car by way of a background LogUpdater actor task?

Comment: For your info, your code seems to work for me in my tests (using the default SwiftData project).
Typing in the `TextField`, triggers an update to the views (parent and CarView).
Your issue may be due to the Car-Log relationship.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine read the last paragraph again, it’s about updates done in the actor in a background thread.

Comment: I'll show my test code in an answer, since it is not possible in a comment.

Comment: you need a `Query` or update manually

Comment: I was thinking about `@Query` as a hack... is there a good way to fetch just 1/first?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have some id or property observed by SwiftUI that changes. Since this is for a single instance and you use the identifier when calling the actor we can use this identifier as a `@State` property together with `.task(id:)` to trigger a view update when the actor is done with the update

Property

```
@State private var updateId: Car.ID?
```

Button action

```
updateId = car.id
```

and the task

```
.task(id: updateId) {
    guard let updateId else { return }
    let logUpdater = LogUpdater(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
    do {
        try await logUpdater.update(updateId)
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
    self.updateId = nil // This will trigger the view update
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To `Re-render View after updating @Bindable object from background task` use this approach using the
`id()` of the View to (force) a refresh when we want to do so.

The following example code with your `Car` model and your `LogUpdater`, shows that after you have completed the `Task`,  change the `refresh` value
and the view will refresh, displaying the new `car` info as per the requested question.

Note, View identity is crucial in SwiftUI to efficiently identify what has
changed in the view and how to refresh it (or parts of it).

EDIT-1:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData


@main
struct TestApp: App {
    
    var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
        let schema = Schema([Car.self])
        let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)
        do {
            return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
        } catch {
            fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)")
        }
    }()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
        .modelContainer(sharedModelContainer)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    @Query private var cars: [Car]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationSplitView {
                List {
                    ForEach(cars) { car in
                        NavigationLink {
                            Text("Item \(car.name)")
                        } label: {
                            Text("Item \(car.name)")
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                }
                .toolbar {
                    ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                        EditButton()
                    }
                    ToolbarItem {
                        Button(action: addItem) {
                            Label("Add Car", systemImage: "plus")
                        }
                    }
                }
            } detail: {
                Text("Select a Car")
            }
            if !cars.isEmpty {
                CarView(car: cars[0])
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func addItem() {
        withAnimation {
            let newItem = Car(name: String(UUID().uuidString.prefix(5)), logs: [Log(km: .random(in: 100...200))])
            modelContext.insert(newItem)
        }
    }
    
    private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
        withAnimation {
            for index in offsets {
                modelContext.delete(cars[index])
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CarView: View {
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext: ModelContext
    @Bindable var car: Car
    
    @State private var refresh = false // <--- here, or something similar

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            TextField("Car Name", text: $car.name).border(.red)
            Text("logs: \(car.logs.count)")
            Text("kms: \(car.logs.map(\.km).reduce(0, +))")
            Button {
                // How to get this to re-render the view after the update to the Bindable Car?
                Task {
                    let logUpdater = LogUpdater(modelContainer: modelContext.container)
                    try await logUpdater.update(car.persistentModelID)
                    refresh.toggle()  // <--- here
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Update")
            }.buttonStyle(.bordered)
        }
        .id(refresh)  // <--- here
        .padding()
    }
}

@ModelActor
actor LogUpdater {
    
    // mimics background network call update
    func update(_ identifier: PersistentIdentifier) async throws {
        guard let car = modelContext.model(for: identifier) as? Car else { return  }
        var logs = [Log]()
        for _ in 0...10 {
            let log = Log(km: .random(in: 100...200))
            logs.append(log)
        }
        car.logs.append(contentsOf: logs)
        try modelContext.save()
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, is this WIP? Because this piece of code directly comments out the part that I am struggling with and asking about?

Comment: Yes, this was just my test code to show that the views re-render
 after updating the @Bindable object.

 Updated my answer using your specific `Car` model, to show how to re-render the view. Let me know if this does not work for you.